# Numerous questions about advanced guitar tablature notation

Tags: guitar, software, notation, tablature

[image]
8 slide 0...why is 0 in parentheses?

[image]
7 slide 9...what does curve under mean?

[image]
5 7 5..7 5 0..are they hammers or pull offs..how you distinguish those

[image]
how to play this?

[image]
what does this long line mean?

[image]
15 slide 17 with curve and 17 slide 19 with no curve...what is difference?

Comment: This is pretty standard notation, not just for Guitar Pro.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll answer each of your questions in order:

The notes in parentheses are ghost notes. You should play them quietly - certainly don't emphasize them. They do have *rhythmic* value, however (i.e. they aren't grace notes).

The 7 to 9 slide is a legato slide. Pick the 7, then slide to 9, but don't pick again for the 9.

The 5-7-5, 7-5-0 are indeed hammer-ons and pull-offs. The same legato notation works for both: if a note is followed by a higher note, it will be a hammer-on; if it is followed by a lower note, it will be a pull-off. So in your example, 5-7-5 is a hammer-on (5-7) followed by a pull-off (7-5). The 7-5-0 would be two pull-offs (7-5, 5-0).

I'm not entirely sure about the next one (in this case it might help to see the staff notation). Certainly you would play the chord and then play the hammer-ons and pull-offs on the top line (B string). Possibly you should keep the rest of the chord fretted so it will ring, or at least the 6 on the G string for a gentle pull-off to (0) at the end. But I'm not certain.

The 14-12-14-12 etc with the long line over-top is a long series of pull-offs and hammer-ons.

The 15 to 17 slide with the legato marking has the same meaning as the 7 to 9 slide in your first question: pick 15, slide to 17, don't pick again. The 17 to 10 slide means pick the 17, slide to 19, and pick again.

Comment: thx, detailed answer